# Scroll to a div is not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

On a `button click` I want to `scroll` to a particular `div`. Initially the `div` is `hidden`.Two things are happen on my `button click`

> 1. The div should visible (it is working) and
> 2. Scroll to this div (not working)

My code is :

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="showbtn" value='Show'>
<div id="ref_div" style="display:none;">
<span class="small">Reference Number</span>
<input type="text" name="rnum" id="rnum" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" placeholder="Reference Number" title="Reference Number"><br>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="ref_btn" name="ref_btn" value="Proceed"><br>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#showbtn").click(function() {
    $("#ref_div").css('display', 'block');
});

$("#ref_btn").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#ref_div").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: really? `display: none;` ?

Comment: @next2u I think you are trying impossible thing :)

Comment: You want to click on a button which is not rendered (display: none) and scroll to that div (in which you've just clicked), just a question: WTF ?

Comment: Anyway, a fiddle that will surely help you : https://jsfiddle.net/h5t3edtu/

Comment: sorry I have two buttons...it was an mistake..I edited my question. Show div in one button click and scroll in another button click

Comment: you want to click  *ref_btn*  but it is inside display none. what are you trying :(  .  http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/8tLdq/2129/ see this will help you

Answer (score 0):

`$("#ref_div").css('display','block');`

Can change to:

`$("#ref_div").show();`

Ensure that `height:100%;` or `min-height:100%;` is not set in your stylesheets on the `<html>` and/or `<body>` elements. Usually, this would prevent a jQuery scrollTop animation from working at all.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('document').ready(function() { 
 $('body').css('height','600px') 
 $("#ref_btn").click(function(){
  $("#ref_div").toggle()
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#ref_div").offset().top
      }, 1000);
     });
 })
```

```css
#ref_div{
  width:30%;
  height:10%;
  background:green;
  display: none;
  
}

input#ref_btn
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -187px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<div id="ref_div">
<span class="small">Reference Number</span>
<input type="text" name="rnum" id="rnum" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" placeholder="Reference Number" title="Reference Number"><br>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="ref_btn" name="ref_btn" value="Proceed"><br>
</html>
```

Try this and go to bottom and click the procced button, to scroll to div, you can adjust your button as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how you're trying to achieve this but this is what I would do:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function(e){//event is important
    e.preventDefault();//preventing default action
    $(this.hash).show();//shows your target element
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top
    },500);
});
```

Then you'll need to keep the two elements seperate say like

```
<a href='#show_element'>Show Element!</a>
<div id='show_element'>
    <h1>I have been shown!</h1>
</div>
```